# Crear repositorio git desde rama

Tags: git, ramas-git, git-flow

En uno de mis desarrollos estoy usando el flujo de trabajo `git-flow`.
De momento estoy usando las siguientes ramas:

- master
- dev
- feature

Este repositorio lo tengo conectado a un repositorio remoto alojado en un servidor propio.

Por exigencias del proyecto una de las ramas dentro de `feature` tengo que convertirla en un repositorio independiente, digamos la rama `feature/xxx`

Había pensado hacerlo del siguiente modo:

1. Crear un nuevo repositorio en el servidor
2. Apuntar la rama `feature/xxx` a la rama master del nuevo repositorio
3. Clonar el repositorio remoto nuevo en un proyecto nuevo en local
4. Borrar rama `feature/xxx` del repositorio original

Las preguntas son:

¿Es correcto este razonamiento o hay alguna forma más sencilla de hacerlo?

¿Qué secuencia de comandos debo seguir para conseguirlo?

Comment: Cuando se quiere usar repositorios dentro de repositorios, lo haces usando submodulos, si son solo un grupo de archivos son los que se incluyen en el nuevo repositorio (como una libreria o un plugin).

Si es una version completa (alternativa) de todo el desarrollo, puedes crear un nuevo remoto tal como lo propones , pero localmente puedes mantener uno solo.

Si deseas crear un nuevo desarrollo a partir de uno existente, y estos serán divergentes, si podrias tener 2 remotos y dos locales.

En todo caso, la respuesta depende de qué es para ti un "feature" y que te lleva a independizarla.

Comment: Garcias por tu comentario @gustavovelascoh, efectivamente, el desarrollo de esta nueva funcionalidad ha evolucionado tanto que nos hemos dado cuenta que estamos frente a un desarrollo complentamente nuevo y totalmente divergente del anterior por lo que lo más sensato es separalo no sólo en remoto si no también en local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien, he probado llevar a cabo los puntos que comento en la respuesta y hay algún matiz, el reultado final de los pasos a seguir ha sido el siguiente:

1. Crear un nuevo repositorio en el servidor
2. Apuntar la rama `feature/xxx` a la rama master del nuevo repositorio
3. Hacer `push`al repositorio nuevo
4. Clonar el repositorio remoto nuevo en un proyecto nuevo en local
5. Borrar rama `feature/xxx` del repositorio original

Voy añadiendo los comandos necesarios para crear un repositorio a partir de una rama:

**1. Crear un nuevo repositorio en el servidor:**

Como comento en la pregunta, mi repositorio remoto está en un servidor propio, con lo que esta comando puede variar en función de la aqrquitectura de cada uno. Yo, después de haber accedido mediante una conexión `SSH`sólo tuve que ejecutar la siguiente secuencia de comandos:

```
mkdir nuevorepositorio.git  #Este comando crea el directorio que alojará el repositorio
cd nuevorepositorio.git     #Accedemos al directorio   
git init --bare             #Inicializa el repositorio GIT dentro del directorio
```

**2. Apuntar la rama `feature/xxx` a la rama `master`del nuevo repositorio:**

Con el terminal abierto en el directorio donde se encuentra el repositorio local debemos ajecutar el siguiente comando:

```
git remote add originnuevo usuario@servidorpropio.com:ruta/nuevorepositorio.git
```

Si el desarrollo estuviera alojado en alguna página como `Github`el comando tendría que tener el siguiente fromato:

```
git remote add originnuevo https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Con esto ya hemos hecho que el repositorio local esté apuntando a dos repositorios remostos diferentes, podemos comprobar esta configuración ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
git remote -v
```

Si todo ha ido bien deberemos obtener un resultado como este:

> origin usuario@servidorpropio.com:ruta/repositoriooriginal.git (fetch)
>
> origin usuario@servidorpropio.com:ruta/repositoriooriginal.git (push)
>
> originnuevo    usuario@servidorpropio.com:ruta/nuevorepositorio.git (fetch)
>
> originnuevo    usuario@servidorpropio.com:ruta/nuevorepositorio.git (push)

Podemos ver como están ambos repositorios, el repositorio original `repositoriooriginal`y en nuevo `nuevorepositorio`

**3. Hacer `push`en el nuevo repositorio remoto.**

```
git push originnuevo feature/xxx:master
```

**4. Clonar el repositorio remoto nuevo en un proyecto nuevo en local.**

LLegados a este punto ya tenemos duplicado el repositorio remoto, sólo nos fata crear un nuevo repositorio local donde clonara este repositorio remoto nuevo.

Para esto, con el terminal abierto en la ruta donde queremos que se clone el repositorio ejecutaremos el siguiente comando GIT:

```
git clone usuario@servidorpropio.com:ruta/nuevorepositorio.git
```

Ahora ya tenemos duplicados ambos repositorios, sólo uqedaría 'desconectar' el repositorio remoto nuevo del repositorio local viejo, ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

```
 git remote rm nuevorepositorio
```

Y por último eliminar la rama que hemos convertido en repositorio del desarrollo original

```
git checkout develop                  #Cambiamos a la rama develop para poder eliminar la otra
git branch -D feature/xxx             #Elimina la rama local
git push origin --delete feature/xxx  #Elimina la rama del repositorio remoto
```